# Proof of Belyi's theorem with additional requiremt that ramification indices above 1 are equal to 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to prove an exercise problem from Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups", which is a version of belyi's theorem.

[The exercise in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbWPP.png)

The normal version without the ramification indices of points above 1 was already proven in the book. The part I'm concerned about is constructing such a morphism $X \to P^1$
(thats étale everywhere except 0, 1, $\infty$) where points above 1 have ramification index 2 when assuming that X can be defined over $\overline{Q}$.

My idea was to use the version of beyli's theorem that was already proven to take a morphism $X \to P^1$ thats étale everywhere but at 0, 1 and $\infty$ and compose with a belyi function $P^1 \to P^1$ of the form $x^A(x-1)^B$ for some nonzero integers A and B, in the hope of decreasing the ramification index of one point above 1. If I can do this I am done, since the morphism $X \to P^1$ is finite, so this procedure can be repeated until the ramification indices are equal to 2.

However I do not know, how I would have to choose A and B to decrease the ramification index of some point above 1, if thats even possible. How would I go about doing that, or is there a different way to solve the exercise?

Comment: What happens if you compose a Belyi map with $z\mapsto z^2$?

Comment: The resulting map would still be étale outside of 0, 1 and $\infty$ and the number of elements in the fibres increase for all points in $P^1$ except maybe $\infty$.

Comment: Arent all the points above 0 and infinity ramified?

Comment: Are they? The points above 0 and $\infty$ for the map $z \mapsto z^2$ should still only be 0 and $\infty$ respectively, so the points above 0 and $\infty$ for the composite map remain the same and those are not necessarily all ramified, right? I am probably having some error in my line of thougt however. How would it help with reducing ramification indices above 1 if the points above 0 and $\infty$ are all ramified? I'm a bit lost I fear

Comment: Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer. Consider $z\mapsto z^n$ from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to itself. Then $0$ and $\infty$ are ramified with ramification index $n$. 

Now, let $f:X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a Belyi map  of degree $d$ (unramified outside $0$, $1$, and $\infty$). Compose with $z\mapsto z^2$. The inverse image above $0$ still has $d$ points. But the map is of degree $2d$, so obviously there are ramification points. However, all of these points are now ramified. The same goes for $\infty$. So, we have almost achieved what you want, because ...

Comment: now we just apply an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1$ to shift $0$ to $1$ (or you use a different map, something like $z\mapsto (z-1)^2$ probaby.

Comment: Thanks, with your help I got it now. I think you could also use the map $z \mapsto 4z(1-z)$ to avoid applying an automorphism. The argument would still be the same with this map, only directly for 1.